# Managing SQL schema in F#

Tags: sqlite, orm, f#, relational-database, type-providers

Because of the presence of [type providers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361033.aspx) for accessing SQL data in F#, there's not much focus on the use of ORMs, micro or otherwise. I can definitely see the logic behind this.

It also seems that many examples of using F# to play with relational data is to plug them into existing large databases, that would appear to be created elsewhere.

It feels like there's a bit of a gap here: is there a nice way to manage schema creation and migration directly from F#? The example linked to above suggests running your manual schema creation script as the first step. Is this the only option?

I've recently started a little project that is F# from the outset, and I'm looking at storing some data in a relational database (sqlite for now). I don't have an existing schema to explore, I'm designing from scratch. Is there a friendlier or more idiomatic way to manage my schema (creation and then migration) in F#?

Comment: This is not clear re what "manage schema creation and migration" means. Also your own link mentions 2 libraries, how are they inadequate? "Schema creation" seems basic provider functionality. What does "friendlier or more idiomatic" mean? Why do you even mention ORMs? Are you trying to say by "creation" and/or "migration" that you want to store the state of a F# program that isn't manipulating a DB in a DB a la ORMs?--If so, you really haven't made that clear. (But--*why* do that?) For migration in the DB sense I can see you would want F# access to specialized tools rather than SQL per se.

Comment: Divide and conquer. afaik there's no F#-specific db schema tools, just manage it separately. In our solutions we create a small console project and use dbup to apply and keep track of db migrations: https://www.nuget.org/packages/dbup  . Good enough for us

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You /can/ use Entity Framework with F#, and therefore get the Migrations API that it comes with, but I've found it very painful in practice - all your entity classes will require `member val get set` style properties (I believe) and various other bits and pieces. Jamie Dixon did a blog post on this some months ago around the same time I was experimenting with it - I did not enjoy it!

To be honest, although this isn't a great answer for you given what you're asking for i.e. DB schema management in F# - I would recommend that you use something like VS Database Projects to manage your schema outside of your code, and use (yes) either one of the SQL Type Providers to manage data within your application.

If you're dead set on using a "schema migration in code" system, EF plays much better with C# in my experience, so you could experiment theoretically with e.g. a C# / EF data access project referenced by your F# application code.

Sorry.

Comment: I wasn't even thinking as far ahead as migration, right now I'm even just curious about creation of database objects. I had gone down a similar path as you suggest, although in my case had been trying ServiceStack.Ormlite. For the dialect support alone it seems like a worthwhile 'redundant' investment.

Comment: Sorry - when I said "migration" I was referring to EF's ability to generate a SQL schema based off an set of OO relationships.

Comment: Oh you mean 'migrate class structure to a schema definition', not 'migrate database schema version 1 to 2'? No problem. Either way, I was hoping I might flush out a 'hey check out this awesome blog post/nuget package', but it sounds like that just doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm not sure what this magical solution would even look like, the whole point of type providers is you don't need to create and maintain the artifact classes. I think your general solution of 'use another tool' is the one on the table.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to find a solution for this and I'm more and more inclined to try to fall back to the basics when it comes to SQL databases. One of the major parts described in the book [Refactoring Databases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321293533) is migrations. Having a tool that supports working with migrations solves a lot of problems as long as you can accept to write all up and down scripts in plain ol' SQL would probably be very suitable.

One tool I've found for the .NET stack is Rob Reynold's 
[Roundhouse](https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse). I have yet to try it out but it seems promising albeit somewhat dated.